# Topology of the Scherk surface?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry

The Scherk surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is defined by the equation$$e^z\,\cos(x) - \cos(y) = 0.$$What is the topology of the Scherk surface, i.e. what is a description of it as a surface of some genus with some number of punctures or boundary components?

Comment: Have you tried to make a picture to make a useful guess?

Comment: This is what I would do. Consider the function from the Scherk surface $(x,y,z) \mapsto e^z$ and figure out the critical points and topology of the level sets of that function. (Note the map $z \mapsto e^z$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image hence we can think of the value of $e^z$ as the 3rd coordinate without changing the topology.)

Comment: There can be only one: MR1443545 Reviewed Frohman, Charles; Meeks, William H., III The topological uniqueness of complete one-ended minimal surfaces and Heegaard surfaces in R3. J. Amer. Math. Soc. 10 (1997), no. 3, 495–512.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scherk's surface has infinite genus and one end. You can see that it has infinite genus because when you look down on it you see infinitely many holes. If you remove a large compact set the complement has one unbounded component so it has one end.  It is a theorem of Meeks and I, that any two complete properly embedded minimal surfaces with one end and the same genus are topologically equivalent in the sense that there is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that takes one to the other. We also gave a classification of minimal surfaces with more than one end.